# Получение пути к папке через проводник

Tags: python, pyqt5, файловая-система

Задача простая:
хочу выбрать в открывшемся проводнике папку и получить путь к ней

Нашёл на форуме вырвиглазный рабочий метод

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Form(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def get_directory(self):  # <-----
        return QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Выбрать папку", ".")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Form()

    print(ex.get_directory())
```

Есть ли какое-то более простое решение? Желательно без использования такого гиганта, как PyQt5.
Интернеты мне подсказывают библиотеку easygui, документацию которой сейчас читаю, и даже нашёл метод, который делает то, что я хочу, только для файлов, а не папок (ОС Windows). Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Вы не видели кода на более низких компилируемых языках, если называете это вырвиглазным :)

Comment: @dIm0n, ахаха. да) зажрался. но всё же?

Comment: Ну я думаю, что вы правильно сказали - нужна какая-то библиотека, не припомню стандартного модуля в питоне, который это делает. Ещё как вариант запустить сторонний процесс и получить его результат - минимальное количество питоновского кода будет, но не лучшее решение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью библиотеки Tkinter:

```
import tkinter

foldername = tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory()
```

с помощью библиотеки PyQt5:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
import sys
prg = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
dirlist = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None,"Выбрать папку",".")
sys.exit(prg.ecec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение оказалось до боли элементарным. Не зря я минусы получал на данном вопросе))
(Всегда сначала хотя бы чуть-чуть читайте документацию, прежде чем задавать вопрос!)

```
import easygui
input_file = easygui.diropenbox()
print(input_file)
```

Comment: Можно ещё с помощью [tkinter](https://younglinux.info/tkinter/dialogbox.php)